# how to get custom attribute into header.phtml in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I'm trying to get a custom attribute >> type "text field" into the header.phtml.

To get a custom attribute into a product page it is (view.phtml)

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('medium');?>
```

What is it for getting it into header.phtml?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As  header file is called every page ,`So i have check current page is product by full action`

```
       <?php
 $FullActionName= Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
        if($FullActionName=='catalog_product_view'):
        if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
        $Product=Mage::registry('current_product');
    ?>

    <meta itemprop="description" content= "<?php echo $Product->getMedium();?>" />
      <?php  //echo $Product->getMedium();
        }
        endif;
?>
```

**According to your request  i am putting update code**

```
 <?php
    $FullActionName= Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
    if($FullActionName=='catalog_product_view'){
         if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
             $Product=Mage::registry('current_product');
            if(Mage::registry('my_current_pro')){
            Mage::unregister('my_current_pro');
            }
             Mage::register('my_current_pro',$Product->getId());
             ?>
            <meta itemprop="description" content= "<?php echo $Product->getMedium();?>" />
             <?php   
         }
    }else{
        if(Mage::registry('my_current_pro')){
             $Product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Mage::registry('my_current_pro'));
             ?>
             <meta itemprop="description" content= "<?php echo $Product->getMedium();?>" />
             <?php
        }

    }
```

**But ,most import except product page,rest of page will be showing the meta data basic of last visited product.**

Comment: why my answer is down voted ?

Comment: This is what i use in view.phtml to get a custom attribute

 <meta itemprop="description" content= "<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('medium');?>" />

I now want to get the same custom attribute in the header.phtml

Comment: you can use this code header.phtml... i have test it

Comment: How do I use it with a meta tag?

<meta itemprop="description" content= "<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('medium');?>" />

What do I need to change?

Comment: is you using in header.phtml?

Comment: Yes, just before the <!-- HEADER EOF --> in the header.phtml
I'm implementing schema therefore the meta tag and schema tag of itemprop="description"

Comment: check , i have edit my answer

Comment: It gives me the attribute/catagory ID, I need it to give me the text. Also it needs to be hidden, its currently showing on the front end.

Comment: check again.....

Comment: is medium a product attribute??

Comment: Attribute details

Attribute Code - brand_description | 
Scope - global | 
Apply to - All products | 
Used in product listing - No |

Comment: Ok, it works only for product pages, I need it to work for all pages, is that possible?

Comment: Is it possible to show it for all pages, including home page and catagory pages?

Comment: are you want show to  current visited product details in all pages???

Comment: I want to see the 

<meta itemprop="description" content= "<?php echo $Product->getMedium();?>" /> 

In all the pages. Right now it only shows on product pages.

Comment: it is not good idea...

Comment: Ok, do you have a better solution where I can have an attribute so it shows on all the pages through the header? I need this for displaying schema description for brand, and the schema brand itemscope is within the header.phtml. Thats why I tried to use a attribute to display within the header.phtml under the schema brand itemscope.

Comment: I get this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in

Comment: There is a mistake in the code, I'm getting a parse error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in

Comment: try new code.........

Comment: The new code doesnt seem to work on all pages, Its ok, I will use the old solution you provided. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mage::registry('current_product')->getData('medium')` instead of your code.
`Mage::registry('current_product')->getMedium()` should work too.

Comment: so what will be the full php code? if the attribute name is "medium"

Comment: Just changed the answer, check it please.

Comment: so this will be what the final code will look like?

<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getData('medium');?>

Comment: Yes. It should work.

Comment: neither of the solutions work, it breaks the page. and shows this error

<meta itemprop="description" content="<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getMedium() on a non-object in

Comment: I assumed you had some knowledge in the platform. This will only work on the product page.

Comment: The header.phtml gets used in all the pages correct even the product page. I used this code in the header.phtml just before <!-- HEADER EOF -->. So even if I check a product page it breaks and doesnt show the attribute name.